# why args.ScreenPoint.IsEmpty is true?

Tags: arcgis-server

I use a map control and set a MapClick event for it.

And i have a tool that ClientAction set to point.

Event fired when i clicked on the map.

But args.ScreenPoint was empty.

What's wrong ?

I want get x and y in map click.